# What is this port on my computer?

Tags: port, cable

What is the name of the port shown in the picture?

This port is on my old NEC Versa LitePad Tablet PC

> - http://www.superwarehouse.com/NEC_Versa_LitePad_Tablet_PC/VL-PAD-933/p/243017
> - [http://www.amazon.com/NEC-LitePad-Tablet-933-MHz-Pentium/dp/B00008MNDW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008MNDW)

[image: Mystery port]

Comment: Can you supply a bit more context for the photo please. What device is it on? Roughly how big is it? etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like it is for a CF card.

[image: CF socket]

<sub>Picture from sageshome.net</sub>

Comment: 50 pins, same as CF; I'd guess the same.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that is a Flash Card/PC Card/CardBus/PCMCIA Slot.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_Card

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a typical bay for a 2.5" hard drive.

Comment: IDE has a pin missing in the middle, and only 39/43 pins

Answer (score 2):

People, look at the photo. 2.5" HDDs use a 44-pin connector (standard 40-pin IDE plus four extra pins for power). PC Card (PCMCIA) is 68-pin.

The connector in question is clearly 50-pin, and judging by the rails on the sides (black plastic), the metal ejector foot at the back (right-hand side), and the shallow depth, it's a CompactFlash slot.

Comment: I didn't count. I blame the photo quality! It's all dark over there! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Some kind of bus expansion? These were reasonably common on laptops that mated to base-stations.

It would help if you told us more about the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a PCMCIA slot, but the specs you link to don't list such a slot type. Can you describe where the slot is and its dimensions?